# Extract on "-" delimited in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with some values like 19.99-20.99 (i.e. two numbers separated by a dash).
How would you just take the left or right value?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split("-")`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) on the resulting string and then access the result with index notation, ie `split_result[1]`.

Here's an example:

```
In [5]: my_series = pandas.Series(['19.22-20.11','18.55-34.22','12.33-22.00','13.33-34.23'])

In [6]: my_series[0]
Out[6]: '19.22-20.11'

In [7]: my_series[0].split("-")
Out[7]: ['19.22', '20.11']

In [8]: my_series[0].split("-")[0]
Out[8]: '19.22'

In [9]: my_series[0].split("-")[1]
Out[9]: '20.11'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(['19.99-20.99', '20.99-21.99'])

In [2]: s.str.split('-').str[0]
Out[2]: 
0    19.99
1    20.99
dtype: object

In [3]: s.str.split('-').str[1]
Out[3]: 
0    20.99
1    21.99
dtype: object
```